# CloudFront with long shared cache and short browser cache

Tags: browser-cache, amazon-cloudfront

I'm using CloudFront in front of S3 to serve up images. The origin (S3) sets the following cache headers: `CacheControl: max-age=86400,s-maxage=31536000`. The expectation here is that CloudFront will cache the image for one year, and the browser will cache it for a day. After that, it should hit CloudFront again and get the cached image, and cache the "new" item for the rest of the day.

The issue I'm encountering is that the `Date` header from CloudFront is when it was initially cached in the CDN. So, after one day of being cached in the CDN, the browser no longer caches the images, and hits CloudFront every time. At this point the `Age` of the item has exceeded the `max-age` value. Until the CloudFront item is invalidated or expired, the browser never retrieves the item from its caches.

Is it possible to set this up such that the browser caches each subsequent day, but the CloudFront ttl can be set to something long like a year?